# about OS Detection & device detection using nmap -O IP address

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class NmapFlags {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     try{

          String[] cmdarray = { "nmap","-O","66.110.59.130"}//example trying to find the OS or device detials of this Ip address//
          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
          BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
          String s;
          while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(s);

            }


            r.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

after running this code output I got is:

All 1000 scanned ports on 66.110.59.130 are filtered

All 1000 scanned ports on 66.110.59.130 are filtered

Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details

Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 246.06 seconds

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 246.06 seconds**

Is there any other nmap flags I can use to detect the device type. I tried -A option. I need to find the device details at each hop of trace route.
Please help me with this.

This is just one IP address I have shown as example.

Thanks in advance

Sam.

Comment: Even though this technically contains Java code, this is really about the nmap tool. You should ask on [su]

Comment: Are you just trying to detect the operating system of a remote host?

Comment: my task is to identify the device type & manufacturer name. I have to do traceroute & collect all Ip address, finally find the device at each ip address(hop). I need to build network topology.